# SignalR broadcasts to Everyone even though a group is used

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am imitating LinkedIn's posts and comments system. I want to use SignalR to automatically update the comment section, so I created a group added each user that will go to his news feed page. When anybody starts typing a comment JavaScript in the front end will send the poster id and the post id to the hub and the hub will filter out each friend/user that can see this post using the group. Then it will push the new update to all matching friends/users. Here is my hub code:

```
public void AnnounceComment(int postId, string postUserId)
{
    string userID = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var owner = u.context.Users.Include(u => u.Friends).Where(u => u.Id == postUserId).FirstOrDefault();

    var idList = owner.Friends.Select(f => f.FriendUserID).ToList();

    idList.Add(postUserId);

    Clients.OthersInGroups(idList).AnnounceComment(postId);
}
```

and my on connected is as follows:

```
public  override Task OnConnected()
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name).Wait();

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

my front end:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () { })
    .fail(function () { alert("ERRORRR!!!!!") })

//From client to server talking to it.
function signalrAnnounce(postID,op) {
    $.connection.linkedInHub.server.announceComment(postID,op);
}

$.connection.linkedInHub.client.announceComment = function (message) {

    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, is the issue you are having that SignalR is sending updates to all users instead of the subset of users subscribed to a certain group?

Comment: Yes. Weirdly enough, it works ok on microsoft Edge...but doesn't work as expected on chrome or firefox.

Comment: Have you tried using incognito browser windows? Perhaps you are simply seeing a mixup of authentication cookies/tokens

Comment: I used the incognito browser for the first 3 or 4 times it got stuff right, then it went all messed up and started sending messages to everyone again...weird..